# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors after importing Facebook sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

recently I imported my eclipse project to android studio and it worked perfectly
but when I imported facebook sdk I have got this error Manifest merger failed with multiple errors .
I didn't even use the facebook library yet

Answer (score 0):

it was the min sdk must be  15 or above

```
android:minSdkVersion="15"
```

I found the solution by reading Gradle Console